# Isotope not functioning in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-isotope

I had it working on a test site and when I went to the live WordPress site it will not work at all. Everything loads correctly on the page. I have made sure all the scripts are in the head of my site and they are. I have tried so many things to make it work on the live site but have yet to get it to work. I need isotope to load after all the posts are loaded so I thought using imageLoaded.js might help with that. I am trying to filter the posts after load with checkboxes using isotope js. [The site page which I am having the issue on](https://news.uaf.edu/expertsguide/).

If someone can give me a better way of doing this I would be appreciative. I would be grateful for any and all help given. I am just stumped.

Here is isotope custom js:

```
(function($) {
    $(window).load(function() {
        var $container = $('#expertsPeople'),
            $checkboxes = $('#filters input');

    // if on page with filters
       if ($container.length && $checkboxes.length) {
            $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
                 $container.isotope({
                      itemSelector: '.grid-item',
                      transformsEnabled: false
                 });
             });
            $checkboxes.change(function(){
                 var filters = [];

                 // get checked checkboxes values
                 $checkboxes.filter(':checked').each(function(){
                      filters.push( this.value );
                 });           

                filters = filters.join('');
                $container.isotope({ filter: filters });           

                if(!$container.data('isotope').$filteredAtoms.length){
                       $('#noresults').show();
                 } else {
                       $('#noresults').hide();
                   }       
                 });    

                // reset all filters
               var filterurl = location.search.replace(/^\?/,'').split(/\&/);
                for(var i = 0; i < filterurl.length; i++){
                     var ent = filterurl[i].split(/\=/);
                    if(ent[0].match(/^filter_\d+$/)){
                         $('#' + ent[0]).attr('checked', true);
                    }
                 }        
               $checkboxes.change();

              // reset all filters
             $("#filter-head a").click(function(){
                  $container.isotope({filter: '*'});
                  $checkboxes.filter(':checked').each(function(){
                        $(this).attr('checked', false);
                  });
                 $('#noresults').hide();
                 return false;
             });
         }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Here is a sample of the post items:

```
<div id="expertsPeople" class="noscript" aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true">
     <article id="post-44980" class="grid-item experts-box education mathematics">
         <div class="entry-content">....</div>          
   </article>
   <article id="post-44978" class="grid-item experts-box biomedicine-health">
         <div class="entry-content">....</div>
    </article>
</div>
```

Here is the sample of the checkbox list:

```
  <div class="filter-group" data-filter-group="cat8">
        <ul class="experts-tags">
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="agriculture" class="filter-cb" value=".agriculture"><label for="agriculture"> Agriculture</label>
            </li>
         </ul>
   </div>
```

Comment: You haven't defined a width for your items as per the documentation here in CSS https://isotope.metafizzy.co/#css It should then work. Thereafter you need to restyle the contents padding etc. to make it look as desired.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I had a CSS style in my ÇSS for the grid-items. I went back to my test site and looked over everything where it was working and not sure what it was but copied over the files again and it worked. I hate things like this because I have no clue why it went wrong.